# Using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have these columns:

```
bom.Parent_Material_Number,
bom.Plant,
bom.BOM_Category, 
bom.Base_Quantity,
bom.UoM,
bom.Posnr,
bom.Child_Material_Number,
mm.Material_Descr_HU
```

First I would like to show like this:

```
SELECT
            bom.Parent_Material_Number,
            mm.Material_Descr_HU,
            bom.Plant,
            bom.BOM_Category,
            bom.Base_Quantity,
            bom.UoM,
            bom.Posnr,
            bom.Child_Material_Number
    FROM
            bom
        INNER JOIN
            mm
                ON bom.Parent_Material_Number = mm.Material_Number
    GROUP BY
            mm.Material_Descr_HU;
```

Then I would like to show the columns where the first

```
SELECT Child_Material_Number = Parent_Material_Number
```

Comment: Why do you do GROUP BY?

Comment: so you want to show only the top 1 child from mm table?

Comment: I'm new in sql anyway. I wanna make an Union with 2 select and i wanna show all items where the conditions are met

Comment: since both `Child_Material_Number` and `Parent_Material_Number` come from the  `bom` table they will not vary by `mm`.

Comment: and then let the mm table, can u do that?!

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using ADODB in VB

Comment: To talk to what database engine? Your question is tagged as `sql` and `select`. Both tags are vendor and client agnostic.

Comment: ye it sql and select, coz i want to make my query, MySQL ODBC 3.51

Comment: It is hard to understand your requirement. Can you perhaps provide some samples of your data, and a sample of the result you hope to get?